# ColdFusion: do i need to use structKeyExists for every element of a deep struct?

Tags: coldfusion, struct, key, exists

Let's say i've just parsed someone else's XML document which is a response to an API request. I want to know if a value nested deep inside exists. If my API request worked, it will be in the same place every time. If my API request fails, the root of the XML is very different.

If I try `<cfif structKeyExists(myStruct.level1.level2.level3, 'myTarget')>` on a failed api request, I get the fatal error: `Element LEVEL1.LEVEL2 is undefined in MYSTRUCT`.

Of course, I could try to depend on the root level of the XML telling me of success or failure, and not looking for the result if it failed, but... barring that solution, what should i do?

Do i need to check for the existence of each level of the struct? As in:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(myStruct, 'level1') 
  and structKeyExists(myStruct.level1, 'level2') 
    and structKeyExists(myStruct.level1.level2, 'level3') 
      and structKeyExists(myStruct.level1.level2.level3, 'myTarget')>
<!--- ... --->
</cfif>
```

This is not a real-world problem, this is just something i've faced too many times. Please don't tell me solutions that involve changing the API or solutions like those in the third paragraph.

Thanks!

edit: i should have mentioned why i can't use isDefined() - some of the keys do not have syntactically valid names, so isDefined() throws an error, eg myStruct.level1[42].level3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## XMLSearch

I would use the parsed XML document (i.e. `xmlDoc`) and [XMLSearch](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=xmlsearch#xmlsearch):

```
<cfset xmlDoc = xmlParse(responseData)>
<cfset nodes = XmlSearch(xmlDoc, '/level1/level2/level3/myTarget')>
<cfif arrayLen(nodes)>
    <!--- do something, you have the "nodes" array to work with too --->
</cfif>
```

xpath for `XMLSearch()` assumes the structure keys are nodes. You would need to modify accordingly if, for instance, 'myTarget' is an attribute of a node.

## StructFindKey

Another way of doing this would be [StructFindKey](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=structFind#structfindkey).

```
<cfset result = structFindKey(myStruct, "myTarget")>
<cfif arrayLen(result) AND result.path EQ "level1.level2.level3">
    <!--- do something --->
</cfif>
```

## Conclusion

Haven't tested, but I believe either will be faster than using `IsDefined()` or a try-catch block. Has the advantage over `XMLValidate()` of not needing a DTD. And, even with a DTD, the node you want may be defined as optional, so it could still validate.

Comment: `XMLSearch()` is a good idea, but it's just as much typing and probably still more cycles than the original `<cfif>` in the question. I think `structFindKey()` was the answer i was looking for. i think it would help me out in previous situations, especially if the target key had a variable name. but i think in this case it's more cycles and typing....

Answer (score 3):

You could validate the XML against a DTD to make sure the document was in the right format. `XmlParse()` and `XmlValidate()` both take a DTD as a parameter.

```
<cfset validateResult = XmlValidate(myXmlDocument, myDTD)>
<cfif validateResult.status>
    <!--- xml is valid continue processing --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- xml did not validate handle the error --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the node/attribute in question is defined as optional in DTD. Then it will still validate, but the ColdFusion code will fail.

Comment: @orangepips based on the original question, "If my API request worked, it will be in the same place every time" makes it sound like it is always defined. Could always make a custom DTD that has it defined too incase the web service api has them as optional.

Comment: this is the most interesting solution. i didn't know you could do that. but it does seem like more work than any of the others.

Comment: I would go this route as well. If you have required fields, then the DTD will suss those out. If you have option keys, which the DTD can define, then you can deal with those optional keys with StructKeyExists before acting on them. In this way, you only have to check for optional items before continuing your work instead of having to check for every level of your file. There are several really good online TD generators where you can just pass them an XML file and they'll generate a DTD for you.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't go crazy checking for every level of a 'deep' structure like this. I would presume that if the top level exists the rest of the document will be as you expect, and I'd just address the document from there.

If you wanted you could perhaps try to address the value in your struct and wrap it in a `try/catch`. That way you can handle any errors at any 'level' in the same way.

```
<cftry>

  <cfset myVar = myStruct.level1.level2.level3 />

<cfcatch type="any">
  <!--- Handle error --->
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Hope that helps some.

Comment: yeah, my real world solution is to look for a shallow status var that's always there, which tells me if deeper values exist. the try-catch sounds great, but it's just as much typing and probably more cycles than the complex `<cfif>` i presented in the question.

Comment: I would just say: never assume performance - if in doubt always measure it.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm going to get booed off the stage here, but this is where `isDefined()` can save you a lot of typing:

```
<cfif isDefined(structKeyExists(myStruct.level1.level2.level3)>
<!--- do something --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: So long as there's no large loop involved `isDefined()` is a good way to go.

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned why i can't use `isDefined()` - some of the keys have names that throw errors in `isDefined()` but not in `structKeyExists()`

Comment: I think your code has a bug in it.  Did you mean to write:`isDefined( "myStruct.level1.level2.level3" )`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old, but I'm going to put in an answer here.  I struggled for a good long time with this one, till I found a simple solution.  If I know the structure of the XML already, a simple IsDefined works to test if the node or node attribute exists.  I don't think most people know you can do this, or have tried and failed because they didn't include single quotes in the IsDefined function.

So say I grab some user xml from a web service somewhere and want to display the user's ID.

```
<cfhttp url="https://mycompany.com/mywebservices/getusers" username="me" password="mysecret">
<cfset userXMLDoc = XMLParse(ToString(cfhttp.FileContent).trim())>

<cfif IsDefined('userXMLDoc.Data.Record.User.XmlAttributes.id')>
  <cfdump var="#userXMLDoc.Data.Record.User.XmlAttributes.id#">
<cfelse>
  <cfoutput>Failed: No User ID found</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```